# Is it possible to create a channel or supergroup using Telegram API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need to create a integration with telegram and our product, but I need to automate the telegram integration process and create a supergroup, and create some topics in it.

I have gone through the Telegram Bot API docs, and able to create topic, by giving the bot Admin access and via a API request. But I didn't able to seem to a find a way to create a supergroup with a user's authorization.

I saw some docs related to creating channel using `channels.createChannel` in the Telegram API docs. So, is it possible to use this method/API to create a channel for automation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### api bots don't access to create channel

but you can use [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/)(py) or [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto)(php) to create channel automate
and manage topics.

This function `channels.createChannel` is for [client api](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id) and has nothing to do with [bot api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

Comment: Are there any rails gem or packages with can do the same?

Comment: What do you mean by rails gem?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ruby gems. Like is there any similar packages written in ruby, which does the similar job? If not, is it possible to use the client API in a ruby project and do the mentioned automation, like creating a channel, etc?

Comment: this repository can help: https://github.com/ssut/telegram-rb